# How do I use xbps with an authenticated proxy?

Tags: package-management, proxy, void-linux

How do I use xbps with an authenticated proxy? what configuration do I have to do? I'm looking for an example because I've tried configuring the environment variable and nothing, I'm almost buying a service and creating a VPN server on it to be able to connect without dealing with the proxy, but I'd really like to learn how to connect to a proxy network on voidlinux xbps.

What I tried and did not succeed so far:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://user1:123@162.16.78.1:3128
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://user1:123@162.16.78.1:3128
export FTP_PROXY=http://user1:123@162.16.78.1:3128
```

I've already tried it:

```
 export HTTP_PROXY=http://user1:123@162.16.78.1:3128/
 export HTTPS_PROXY=http://user1:123@162.16.78.1:3128/
 export FTP_PROXY=http://user1:123@162.16.78.1:3128/
```

or:

```
export http_proxy="http://user1:123@162.16.78.1:3128"
export https_proxy="http://user1:123@162.16.78.1:3128"
export ftp_proxy="http://user1:123@162.16.78.1:3128"
```

Am I doing something wrong? do I need to restart some service so that the environment variables are recognized?

If I run the command below after configuring the environment variables, I get the following error:

```
perdugames@perdugames:~$ sudo xbps-install -v -S 
[*] Updating `https://alpha.de.repo.voidlinux.org/current/x86_64-repodata' ...
ERROR: [reposync] failed to fetch file `https://alpha.de.repo.voidlinux.org/current/x86_64-repodata': Connection timed out
```

Which makes me believe that there is some problem with libfetch, that a part of the code is shown in the link below:

https://github.com/void-linux/xbps/blob/a717e53ee7a0720d25720180e3e15cd7f5668cdf/lib/fetch/ftp.c#L1090

https://github.com/void-linux/xbps/blob/a717e53ee7a0720d25720180e3e15cd7f5668cdf/lib/fetch/http.c#L789

But I still have not found where the error or my error is.

***Note: And yes that username and password, as well as the address and ports are correct because when setting the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00proxy` file with this data in a debian like, it works as expected.***

> **up 1**

I tried with:

```
export http_proxy="http://162.16.78.1:3128"
export ftp_proxy="http://162.16.78.1:3128"
export HTTP_PROXY_AUTH="basic:*:user1:123"
And it still does not work for xbps.
```

And it still does not work for xbps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a sudo-related issue.

Sudo commands don't automatically inherit environment variables.

You have to specifically tell sudo to do this.

Add the following line in your visudo config:

Defaults env_keep += "http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy"

Comment: you're right works now.